# Linq to SQL JOIN?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to query names in one table and then use that result to pull the master records into a DataGridView.  So what I need to do is get the names from the interest table that are like what is put into text boxes then use those results to pull the data from the CaseSelector table and set the bindingsource filter to those results.  Why can't I seem to set results to the caseSelectorBindingSourceFilter

```
             var results = from CaseSelector in db.CaseSelectors
                     from Interest in db.Interests
                     where SqlMethods.Like(Interest.First, txtFirst.Text) && SqlMethods.Like(Interest.Last, txtLast.Text)
                     select CaseSelector;

caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = ("CaseNumberKey =" + results);
```

Comment: Are you looking for a join?

Comment: @JakubKonecki Yes a join.  How do I pull the ID from interestresults to join on CaseSeclotr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find examples for LINQ join queries here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

I don't know your DB schema but you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
from c in db.Cases
join i in db.Interest on i.CaseNumberKey equals c.CaseNumberKey
select c
```

Comment: I understand how join queries work but I have no idea how to use the result of the first query to join with the second one.

Comment: Okay I changed the above to reflect the join. How do I set it to the bindingsource.filter???

Comment: You'll want to change your select clause so that you're retrieving the data that actually you want. Then just make that data visible in your UI widget

Answer (score 0):

What you've just retrieved is a SQL Set of the valid caseNumberKeys.

Your casefilter should be something like

```
caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = "CaseNumberKey in " + interestsresultsAsSQLSET;
```

You'll have to iterate over the interestsresults and convert it to the string representation of a SQLSET. If you're feeling lucky, you could just try to .toString() it and see what happens.

```
string interestsResultsAsSQLSet = "(";
//write most of them
for(int i=0; i<interestsresults.size() - 1; i++) {
    interestsResultAsSQLSet.append(interestsresults[i] + ",");
//write the last one, with right paren
interestsresults.append(interestsresults[interestsresults.size() -1] + ")");
```

I write Java all day, ignore my basic language errors. :P

Comment: Thanks Justin! Is there a reference needed for .size and .append?  I am apparently missing one!

Comment: Change append to just the += operator. .size() may be .count() or .length()
Check the C# intellisense.

Comment: If your interestsresults is a var, you'll have to use a foreach(object o in interestsresults) to iterate over it. If you can cast it to a list(.toList()), it'll be easier to work with.

Comment: Jakub Konecki's answer will be easier to implement if you could do that. Just modify the select to get the columns you want. But there could be issues of duplicates and whatnot. Especially if you have a one-to-many relationship between cases and interests. But adding a group by will filter those out.